# Using Vega Lite to display already-aggregated data

Tags: vega-lite

I'm trying to show a stacked bar chart of sums over time. The data looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "date": 12345,
    "sumA": 100,
    "sumB": 150
  },
  ...
]
```

I'm encoding the x axis to the field "date". I need the bar at date 12345 to be stacked with one part being 100 high, and the other, shown in another color, being 150 high.

[Vega Lite seems to expect the raw data](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/stack.html), but this would be too slow. I do this aggregate on the server side to save time. Can I spoon-feed Vega Lite the aggregates like in my example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [fold transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/fold/) to fold your two columns into one, and then the channel encodings take care of the rest. For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMDAoWQIwA0Ux+AtgIJMAMvrSOw4AhJgFZeAX2ZVqtOPAaoATIOE9V-dZzGpJMuRgX0yAZh3cyADgFtdTFdNnUadJWQAslzWEZPLPTAzZyM3RWUwcR8JOyEHVEZGaSMAXSpDTHgAJ1gAO2IAMwB7bI4ySnlIEtxoCvirQMhUwVhSVHJIAGNigg48yEEcAgZUqSoWqkgOWGyAazJaeABPAAdIyAAjWchMqEI8nugASzyAc0WjSAAPRcgV9bJIUpO8vEGoQuPCWqeI3ZcGEgyzuDw2AEd8Pl4MdEDCsAxBF8fnVUNg8EQAVcerhSqC1hs8sUOKd3kjvr80TjOANxhBxlIgA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": 1, "sumA": 100, "sumB": 150},
      {"date": 2, "sumA": 200, "sumB": 50},
      {"date": 3, "sumA": 80,  "sumB": 120},
      {"date": 4, "sumA": 120, "sumB": 30},
      {"date": 5, "sumA": 150, "sumB": 110}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["sumA", "sumB"], "as": ["column", "value"]}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "ordinal", "field": "date"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "value"},
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "column"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This even answered the more general question and is applicable to other aggregations too. Thank you!