# vega lite Infinite extent for field "field_start": [Infinity, -Infinity]

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, vega-lite

I have code for stacked bar chart, got from [Using Vega Lite to display already-aggregated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212634/using-vega-lite-to-display-already-aggregated-data)
it works in vega editor

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"bin": "[-inf,8.0)", "bad_distr": 0.009210526315789473, "good_distr": 0.07763157894736843},
      {"bin": "[8.0,14.0)", "bad_distr": 0.075, "good_distr": 0.21842105263157896},
      {"bin": "[14.0,16.0)", "bad_distr": 0.009210526315789473, "good_distr": 0.05394736842105263},
      {"bin": "[16.0,44.0)", "bad_distr": 0.16052631578947368, "good_distr": 0.3236842105263158},
      {"bin": "[44.0,inf)", "bad_distr": 0.04078947368421053, "good_distr": 0.031578947368421054}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["bad_distr", "good_distr"], "as": ["bad", "good"]}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"type": "ordinal", "field": "bin"},
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "good"},
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "bad"}
  }
}
```

Plot comes out good

[image]

Same data, I have in elastic database,

[image]

same code is throwing warning and plot not coming up

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.4.json",
  "title": {
    "text":  "Bin Plot",
    "fontSize":14
  },
  "data": {
    "url" : {
        "index": "scorecard_bin_plot",
        "body": {
          "size":10000,
          "_source": ["bin","good_distr","bad_distr"]
        }
      }  
      "format": {"property": "hits.hits"},
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["_source.bad_distr", "_source.good_distr"], "as": ["bad", "good"]}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"type": "ordinal", "field": "_source.bin"},
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "good"},
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "bad"}
  }
}
```

I don't understand the issue

Using elastic and kibana 7.12.0

Comment: Hello Mr.Negative Voting Genius, Why this was negative voted? Is this a bad question, or you dont know the answer? Whether stack overflow is only for people who know everything or people who want to know things

Comment: Why did you delete your comment?

Comment: Can u also tell me how u got this data in ur elk cluster? I am trying to reproduce the same issue

Comment: did you solve this problem? If you solve it, please share for me!

Answer (score 1):

When using Vega, not Lite, with data from Elastic instead of hardcoded, it seems that in the transform functions the new field should be called "data" and get the data from the field in the format function. Like:

```
"format": {"property": "data_from_elastic"},
"transform": [{"type": "someType", "field":"data"}]
```

Maybe you can use `_source` in `"property"`, call it `data`, and below use it as `data.good_distr` and `data.bad_distr`.